# How do i get a Visualforce Email Template Id from WITHIN the the message body?

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I'm trying to pass the id of the Visualforce email template in a url parameter for a link within the same email. This is the idea:

{!This.EmailTemplate.ID}

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: So far I haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: Work Around :populate EmailTemplate Id into a cutom field on the object using a trigger.
and just refer it as {!relatedTo.TemplateId__c}